# fan is constantly running in my laptop 13.10

Tags: fan

I installed 13.10 on my laptop and it seems as if the fan is constantly running. This is on a sony vaio ultrabook, the fan keeps running even if the cpu load is low. This problem does not occur when running windows, it will turn itself on/off when needed. I have searched posts on this forum for the same problem but none of the solutions worked for me.

Edit: Thank you, let me know if you need more information.

pc info: https://i.stack.imgur.com/APFDj.jpg

*-display

```
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:59 memory:f6400000-f67fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! You will need to provide more information. Yesterday, another user asked the same question, but he also didn't provide enough info. Take a look at [the post](http://askubuntu.com/q/437548/62483), see the comments, and add information *editing* your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us i) whether the machine actually hot and ii) what is the output of `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`.

Comment: Also, it would really help to know which solutions have already been exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing lm-sensors and hddtemp

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors hddtemp libsensors4 xsensors
```

and then, run

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

Follow the instructions closely. You can safely accept all the defaults EXCEPT the final option. The final test may cause problems so you might want to skip the very last one. Reboot for the changes to take effect.

you can check temp by running

```
watch -n 1 -d sensors
```

Also, download the intel graphics installer from here

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads